# How to retrieve the most recent row meeting a certain condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This is my data table:

```
sessionid | page   | category | productid | time
1         | detail | 3        | 4         | 20150303 1002
1         | cart   | null     | 4         | 20150303 1003
2         | detail | 5        | 3         | 20150303 1005
2         | detail | 5        | 3         | 20150303 1007
2         | detail | null     | 2         | 20150303 1008
2         | cart   | null     | 3         | 20150303 1010
2         | detail | 1        | 3         | 20150303 1013
```

This is my expected output

```
sessionid | page | category | productid | time          | refercategory 
1         | cart |  null    | 4         | 20150303 1003 | 3
2         | cart |  null    | 3         | 20150303 1010 | 5
```

Basically I want to look at only cart events, and grab the category field from the most recent detail row prior to the event, that has a non-null category value and same productid.

So for the last cart event with sessionid = 2, I would go up until I hit the detail page with same sessionid (=2), same productid (=3) and non-null category value (=5).

I tried joining (but couldn't limit to one result) and lag (but couldn't filter the pages properly). I would appreciate any tips regarding this confusing issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with hive/hiveql, so I'll answer with generic SQL.

```
select t1.sessionid, t1.page, t1.category, t1.productid, t1.time, t2.category as refercategory 
from table1 as t1
join table1 as t2 on t1.sessionid  = t2.sessionid and t1.productid = t2.productid
where t1.page = 'cart'
and t2.time = (select max(time) 
               from table1 as t3
               where t3.sessionid = t2.sessionid and category is not null)
```

Here is the result using your test data:

```
sessionid   page    category    productid   time            refercategory
1           cart    (null)          4       20150303 1003   3
2           cart    (null)          3       20150303 1010   5
```

Here is a fiddle showing it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38f7b0/4

---

**EDIT** To match the revised question/data I revised the query to:

```
select t1.sessionid, t1.page, t1.category, t1.productid, t1.time, t2.category as refercategory 
from table1 as t1
join table1 as t2 on t1.sessionid  = t2.sessionid and t1.productid = t2.productid
where t1.page = 'cart'
and t2.time = (select max(time) 
               from table1 as t3
               where t3.sessionid = t2.sessionid 
               and category is not null
               and t3.time <= t1.time)
```

The only change is the addition of `and t3.time <= t1.time` to ensure the time on the selected refercategory row is less than the cart row.

Here is the new fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a08ed/3

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! Here, how do I make sure that I'm pulling detail row that happened "prior" to the cart event?

Comment: To clarify I've edited the category and time on the last row. Now your fiddle pulls 1 as refercategory rather than the 5 I intended..

Comment: Thanks! This works great in SQL. I think the only problem is that Hive doen't allow me to use a subquery after t2.time = (). Any workarounds?

Comment: I don't do hiveql, but if I read [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select) and [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) correctly, you can have sub-selects. If it doesn't work as written, try `t2.time in (select max(time)` instead.